# VSTO Outlook ItemAdd not being fired when incoming e-mail is moved by rule to subfolder

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have an Outlook VSTO add-in. I want to respond to incoming emails. This works quite well with the declaration

```
Public WithEvents items As Outlook.Items
```

And the definition for the items that are observed. (I'm afraid that's why only "Inbox" is watched):

```
inbox = objOutlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
items = inbox.Items
```

and the eventhandler

```
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object) Handles items.ItemAdd
```

Even if Outlook is closed, an event is triggered for each new email when Outlook is started.

I've now noticed that some users of the add-in have created a rule that moves incoming emails to a subfolder of "Inbox". In this case, the `Items_ItemAdd` event is **not** fired when a new email arrives.

How can I also capture these new emails that are moved via a rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item is moved on the server side by the server side rule, and even if Outlook was running, it could've been moved before Outlook downloaded the original item to the OST store. So if `ItemAdd` event fires, it only fires on the folder where the item was moved to, not in the Inbox folder.

Besides watching the Inbox folder, you'd need to watch the other folders that the rules might point to - retrieve the rules using `Store.GetRules()`, loop through all rules, check if `Rule.MoveToFolder` action is enabled, and if yes, retrieve the target folder from `MoveOrCopyRuleAction.Folder` property.

Comment: I'll definitely try that.
I just don't really know how I then can watch this dynamic list of folders, since the number and names of the folders are only determined at runtime. Is it possible to watch a whole folders list with one "WithEvents"?

Comment: Create a wrapper class that stores an instance of the `MAPIFolder` and `Items` objects and handles the appropriate events. At runtime, you can create as many wrapper classes as you need and store them in a list (to ensure they are not released by the Garbage Collector).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class which is fired once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. Use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

Also you may track the items in the folders by combining multiple mechanisms like this event handler plus getting new items at startup to not skip any of them that was added silently. The `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class can help you with such tasks. Read more about that in the series of articles:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)